# How to build sparse matrix based on pandas table?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have pandas DataFrame where each row is of the following format:

```
 i   j   d
----------
10  24 0.6
```

How to efficiently build and fill sparse matrix (from scipy.sparse) by values using **i** and **j** as row and column indices and **d** as value?

The sparse matrix is square with known number of rows and columns **K**. All the numbers in columns **i** and **j** are less than **K**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
coo_matrix((df.d.values, (df.i.values, df.j.values)), shape=(K,K))
```